# Nginx rewrite, from htaccess-files

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I've got a PHP-project set up in this directory tree:

- project

  - v1

    - app (project files)
    - public

      - index.php (controller of app)
      - documentation

        - php files
      - examples

        - php files

With "project" being the root of the webserver.

I want to skip the "public" segment of the URL, but keep the "v1":

```
http://myserver.com/v1/whatever/1
```

and not

```
http://myserver.com/v1/public/whatever/1
```

I got it working with this:

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ /v1/public/index.php?_url=/$1;
```

Also I want to be able to serve the files inside **"documentation"** and **"examples"** by this URL-structure:

```
http://myserver.com/v1/documentation/file_name.php
http://myserver.com/v1/examples/file_name.php
```

I had it working in Apache with these two .htaccess-files:

```
#/project/v1/.htaccess

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]
RewriteRule  (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

```
#/project/v1/public/.htaccess

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
```

I have failed in trying to convert these settings to Nginx. This is my result:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name mysite.com;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    set $root_path '/var/www/html/project';
    root $root_path;

    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /v1/public/index.php?_url=/$1 break;
    }

    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index /index.php;

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~* ^/(css|img|js|flv|swf|download)/(.+)$ {
        root $root_path;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the complete vhost configuration? It might affect the rules, so it is needed for context.

Comment: Added Nginx vhost config in original post

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need the `location ~* ^/(css|img|js|flv|swf|download)/(.+)$` block, because it doesn't change anything. Also, in general, `root` directory inside `location` blocks isn't what you usually want, `alias` is the thing you most likely want.

But to the actual problem, try adding these location blocks:

```
location /v1/documentation/ {
    rewrite ^/v1/documentation/(.+)$ /v1/public/documentation/$1 last;
}

location /v1/examples/ {
    rewrite ^/v1/examples/(.+)$ /v1/public/examples/$1 last;
}
```

An optional optimization for your `@rewrite` block

```
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^ /v1/public/index.php?_url=$uri break;
}
```